# Javascript CSS if statement

Tags: javascript, css

I Just started playing with javascript and css today. Would anybody mind explaining to me why this if statement never returns true.

```
if (document.getElementById('girl1').style.backgroundColor == '#65bd77') {  
  alert("true");
}
```

Even though its hard coded to be that background color at the moment.

I figured it out. Its

```
if (document.getElementById('girl1').style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(101, 189, 119)'){
 //    
}
```

Comment: Did you get the ID wrong? DId you forget to wait for DOM load? We can only guess without seeing more.

Comment: WHat is the output, if you just do alert(document.getElementById('girl1').style.backgroundColor) ?

Comment: I'm wondering about the reason the other downvoter has removed his vote.

Comment: Did you even check the error log? If the element couldn't be found, you should see an error message there.

Comment: I think its because .style.backgroundColor returns rgb(#,#,#) gonna try this approach

Comment: @user2647561 you can verify that by logging the value; have you tried that?

Comment: (also, you should use `console.log` instead of `alert`. `alert` is limited to strings, while the console can display much more. Also, it matters less if you forget one in production code)

Comment: @JanDvorak: That depends... a forgotten `alert` won't crash the code, while a `console.log` will do in some browsers.

Comment: @Guffa in IE8, you mean? I'd rather face failing code in 1% cases than obnoxious alerts in 100% cases. Also, you can fix that by polyfilling `console`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the color is not returned in that specific format.

I tried this in Firefox, IE and Chome, and it works there:

```
if (document.getElementById('girl1').style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(101, 189, 119)'){
  alert("true");
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/3CcA4/

However, you should try to find a different way to check whatever it is that you are looking for, as the CSS format returned might not be the same in every current and future browser. You could for example use a class instead of setting the style directly on the element, that is easier to check for reliably.

Comment: Learning slowly, thanks forthe tips

Comment: @user2647561 if this helps than accept the answer by clicking on the tick besides the answer